# How do you write a table to DB using DBI/dbplyr and preserve date field?

Tags: sql, r, tidyverse, dbi, dbplyr

When I use `{DBI}` and `{dbplyr}` to write a table containing a date-type field to a database, the field is forced to a character. How do I make it write to the SQL Server database table as a date type?

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(dbplyr)

con.write <- dbConnect(drv = odbc(),
                       Driver = "SQL Server",
                       Server = "MYSERVER",
                       Database = "MYDATABASE")

cars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(AsOfDate = as.Date('2022-01-24'))
```

Check to see the class of the date field:

```
> class(cars$AsOfDate)
[1] "Date"
```

Now write to the database and re-read from the database.

```
dbWriteTable(con.write, name = "tmp_mtcars",
             value = cars, row.names = TRUE)

dbcars <- tbl(con.write, "tmp_mtcars") %>% collect()
```

Observe the class of the field we just wrote to the database:

```
> class(dbcars$AsOfDate)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: *That* ODBC driver for SQL Server is **ancient**, I suggest you update to something from the last decade such as https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567. That may fix your issue right there. (You may already have it installed, see if `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` includes `"ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"`, in case use that in your `Driver=`.)

Comment: @r2evans Ha, thanks so much for the recommendation. I'll try that.

Comment: @r2evans When I try it, I get an error message: Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 08001: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Odd, in all of my testing with different ODBC versions connecting to SQL Server, the differences were all in *data*, not in the connection itself. I can't really help there, maybe your DBA can provide some insight based on server logs?

Comment: If it matters, my connection args: `dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", database="mydatabase", encrypt="yes", trustservercertificate="yes", server=""myserver", uid="myuser", pwd="mypass")`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your connection string! This might be an organizational IT issue, and I submitted a ticket. I'll get back with the solution if I can find one.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use `as.POSIXct` instead of `as.Date`:

```
cars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(AsOfDate = as.POSIXct('2022-01-24'))

dbWriteTable(con.write, name = "tmp_mtcars",
             value = cars, row.names = TRUE)

dbcars <- tbl(con.write, "tmp_mtcars") %>% collect()

> class(dbcars$AsOfDate)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I'm not sure what the functional effects are for using `as.Date` vs `as.POSIXct`.